# Pymongo threading error while connecting to remote server from google app engine

Tags: python, mongodb, google-app-engine, pymongo

I have deployed a Flask application on Google App Engine. I am connecting to MongoDB hosted at google compute engine using pymongo.

Here is my snippet:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient, ASCENDING, DESCENDING

serveraddress = 'my_server_address'
client = MongoClient(serveraddress, 27017)
db = client['MasterData']
MJCollection = db['StoredJsons']
print MJCollection.count()
```

This gives an output but the process stops: This is the error:

```
Thread running after request. Creation traceback:
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/runtime.py", line 152, in HandleRequest
    error)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 329, in HandleRequest
    return WsgiRequest(environ, handler_name, url, post_data, error).Handle()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~appname-frontend/1.386781073242991356/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from dbHandler import get, update
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~appname-frontend/1.386781073242991356/dbHandler.py", line 9, in <module>
    client = MongoClient(serveraddress, 27017)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~appname-frontend/1.386781073242991356/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 372, in __init__
    executor.open()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~appname-frontend/1.386781073242991356/pymongo/periodic_executor.py", line 64, in open
    thread.start()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in start
    _start_new_thread(self.__bootstrap, ())
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/runtime.py", line 82, in StartNewThread
    return base_start_new_thread(Run, ())
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this configuration is not going to work.
Pymongo MongoClient creates a couple of threads when connected for monitoring purposes etc. GAE wouldn't allow that.

The reason you are geting the exemption on MJCollection.count() and not on client = MongoClient(serveraddress, 27017) is that this is the time MongoClient tries to connect.

Your alternatives are :

- Use mongoDB's REST API but then you will get penalized on
  functionality and speed.
- Move your flask appl to Compute Engine

Answer (score 0):

PyMongo 2.7 used to work on Google App Engine when we use :

```
serveraddress = 'my_server_address'
client = MongoClient(serveraddress, 27017)
db = client['MasterData']
MJCollection = db['StoredJsons']
print MJCollection.count()
```

But for PyMongo 3.0 we need to create a class and then create an object for it.

```
class MongoDB(object):
def __init__(self):
    client = MongoClient(server_address)
    self.db = client[db_name]

def get_collection(self,collection_name):
    return self.db[collection_name]
```

Wherever we want to use them create an object and use it.

Let me know if you face any difficulty.